# TypeError returned from my Twitter script

Tags: python, twitter, typeerror

I'm new to Python (and programming in general), so I've hunted around for an obvious answer to my question, however nothing has come up so far...

I'm working through Head First Programming, and it's instructing me to use a script that it hasn't explained - so there is little guidance on how to fix it if it isn't working.

The script is as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import time

def send_to_twitter(msg):
    password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgr()
    password_manager.add_password("Twitter API",
                              "http://twitter.com/statuses", "username", "password")
    http_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
    page_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(http_handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(page_opener)
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode( {'status': msg} )
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", params)
    resp.read()

def get_price():
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans.itcarlow.ie/prices.html")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find('>$')
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    return float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])

price_now = input("Do you want to see the price now?(Y/N)")
if price_now == "Y":
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
    price = 99.99
    while price > 4.74:
        time.sleep(900)
        price = get_price()
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
```

The point of the script is to pull a price from a website and post it to Twitter. There seems to be some problem with the part that posts the price to Twitter, however, as it comes back with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/e53554/Desktop/Misc/Python/Portable Python 3.2.5.1/coffee", line 25, in <module>
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
  File "C:/Users/e53554/Desktop/Misc/Python/Portable Python 3.2.5.1/coffee", line 12, in send_to_twitter
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", params)
  File "C:\Users\e53554\Desktop\Misc\Python\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\lib\urllib\request.py", line 139, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\e53554\Desktop\Misc\Python\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\lib\urllib\request.py", line 368, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Users\e53554\Desktop\Misc\Python\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1071, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

So if anyone could offer some guidance on what's going wrong and how I can fix it, I would be eternally grateful!

Kind regards

Jonny

Answer (score 0):

`send_to_twitter(bytes(get_price()))` ?

Comment: If you feel this is the correct answer to the question, please explain why instead of just posting your code.